# Theme are different between different user

Tags: theming

I grant permission of menu ['node/add'] to a certain role of users (which was only accessible by admin previously). Turns out that, these two types of users have different views of this menu (As you can see from the following two screen shots).

How can I theme the page for these two users in the same way? Or How can I change the theme for the non admin user?

-----------update-----------

If I don't want to use admin theme, where should I add my own theme?

[image: log in as normal user]

[image: log in as admin group]

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to /admin/people/permissions
2. Enable the "View the administration theme" permission for the appropriate role.
3. Save the form.

Users with that role will now see the admin theme (as set at /admin/appearance) wherever applicable.

Comment: If I don't want to use admin theme, where should I add my own theme?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but for more advanced theme switching see the [ThemeKey](https://drupal.org/project/themekey) module. I mentioned the admin theme specifically because that's what your question refers to

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *disable* the special admin theme for the admin users, navigate to *Administration » Appearance* (path: `/admin/appearance`).

A bit down on the page, there is a box with the title "Administration theme" that let you choose the theme for the admin users.  Choose "Default theme" to always use the same theme as the rest of the site.  After changing this setting, click "Save configuration".